# c++ irc bot only receives data once

Tags: c++

I'm creating a simple IRC bot in C++ but I'm coming across some issues I can't seem to resolve. My code is based on [Beej's Networking Guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html).

Also have I used following [code](http://www.the-tech-tutorial.com/simple-c-irc-bot-template) to try and fix my problem.

**main.cpp snippet**

```
        // as long we don't lose connection, keep receiving data
        while(true) {
            num_receives++;

            if(num_receives == 3) {
                snd("NICK q1w2\r\n");
                            snd("USER q1w2 0 * :q\r\n");
            }

            if(num_receives == 4) {
                snd("JOIN q1w2\r\n");
            }

            num_bytes = recv(s, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0);
            buf[num_bytes]='\0';

            std::cout << num_receives << "\t" << buf;   

            if(num_bytes == -1) {
                            perror("ERROR receiving");
                            break;
                    } 
            if(num_bytes == 0) {
                            perror("DISCONNECTED");
                break;
                    }
        }
```

and the **output** is (first line is command to run the bot)

```
~$ ./bot irc.snt.utwente.nl 6667 

1   :irc.snt.utwente.nl 020 * :Please wait while we process your connection.
2   ERROR :Closing Link: [unknown@91.177.66.186] (Ping timeout)
DISCONNECTED: Network is unreachable
```

So, the problem is that it only receives data once. Even though it's placed in a while loop. I don't really see what's blocking it from looping or receiving. If I place a *cout* inside the while loop you can see it only loops once and a second time in the end when it disconnects.

Edit: I have it working. The commands send to the severs should be put outside the while loop. Because inside the loop it's waiting to be initialized. But as w don't receive anything we just lose connection because we didn't send anything either.

**[correct] main.cpp snippet**

```
        snd("NICK q1w2\r\n");
        snd("USER q1w2 0 * :q\r\n");
        snd("JOIN q1w2\r\n");

        // as long we don't lose connection, keep receiving data
        while(true) {
            num_receives++;

            num_bytes = recv(s, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0);
            buf[num_bytes]='\0';

            std::cout << num_receives << "\t" << buf;   

            if(num_bytes == -1) {
                            perror("ERROR receiving");
                            break;
                    } 
            if(num_bytes == 0) {
                            perror("DISCONNECTED");
                break;
                    }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to implement the IRC protocol.

Your code assumes that each call to the TCP connection's `recv` function will return exactly one IRC message. This assumption is totally and completely invalid. The TCP implementation has no idea what an IRC message is. You have to implement the IRC protocol and the IRC protocol's definition of a message if you want to count how many messages you've received.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But at this point I don't see why that'd be the problem. The problem is that it only receives one line and another line after it's disconnected. Somehow it doesn't loop untill disconnecting

Comment: @Kosumosushi How do you know it only receives one line? You have no code to detect lines. What code determines how many lines were received? You have *no* code that understands what a line is and counts them.

Comment: There is no code that counts the lines, yes. But the *cout of buf* shows only one line. That's where I base myself on.

Comment: @Kosumosushi I tried connecting to that chat server, and the same thing happens to me. It sends me that "Please wait" line and then disconnects me.

Comment: As in, with the same code or something different ? And for reading *buf*, is there another way to read it and be sure everything is read. Because the code in the second link I posted uses a similiar way of receiving data.

Comment: The code in that second link is hopelessly broken for the same reason. If one call to read gets `PI` and the next one gets `NG ...`, it will not find `PING` in either buffer, not realize that it was pinged, and fail horribly. I don't know how I can say this more clearly -- if you want to make an IRB bot, you *must* implement the IRC protocol somewhere.

Comment: Ok, thank you. The weird thing is though that I got the second link working.

Comment: @Kosumosushi That's why this kind of mistake is so insidious. The code can appear to work under some circumstances, and then fail horribly under slightly different circumstances. A lot of Windows software in the early 2000's had these kinds of bugs, and they all started failing when used with certain software firewalls and VPNs. (Do you understand why this is fundamentally broken? TCP does not glue bytes together, but this assumes the `PI` is somehow glued to the `NG` by TCP.)

Comment: Yes, indeed, I understand. Thank you. I will try to remake it but different. And I'll also implement more of the IRC protocol.